# how to Add validations to flag values out of range/below range in typescript

Tags: typescript, micro-frontend

The text boxes for values on vitals and height/weight allows values that are not within range without giving a user notification that the values are out of range.

The initial
validation seems to work in the background since when you try to save with out of range values an error is thrown: Oops! An unexpected error occurred.

Suggestion

write a script to  Validate a text box to flag and "NOTIFY" users when out of range/below range values are keyed
in.